# Prefilled Forms and Repeating Sections

Tags: cognito-forms

We have customers send us in service requests each week, which could involve any number of apartment units that we might need to service in one visit.

I would like to have one form that the customer fills out, with a repeating section for them to enter as many units as they need with details about what service is required.

I then want to have another form that the technician can use to view those unit numbers and details from the customer as well as enter their notes about service completed.

Is there a way to do this?